# Portal-Vue: How to use MountingPortal?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I like to use MountingPortal to teleport an element (later a Component) to `<body>`. But the element is not moved to the target.

**Setup**

1. Create a Vue app with `vue create portal-test` and choose Vue 2 and all defaults
2. Add Vue-Portal: `npm install --save portal-vue`
3. Edit main.js: add `import PortalVue from 'portal-vue'` and `Vue.use(PortalVue)`

In packages.json under `"dependencies"` I've found `"portal-vue": "^2.1.7",`

**Add portal target in public/index.html**

In the body I add a div with id `target-id` that should be treated as a portal target:

```
  <body>
    <noscript>
      <strong>We're sorry but <%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %> doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
    </noscript>
    <hr />
    <div id="target-id">
      Hey
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="app"></div>

    <!-- built files will be auto injected -->
  </body>
```

**Change App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <MountingPortal name="destination" mountTo="#target-id">
    </MountingPortal>

    <portal to="destination">
      <p>This should be rendered outside</p>
    </portal>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Expected output**

The `<p>This should be rendered outside</p>` should displayed between the two `<hr />`.

**Actual output**

The `<p>...</p>` is missing in the DOM. I've tested in Firefox and Edge, the DOM looks the same.

[image: DOM]

Answer (score 1):

Ah, ok, a `<portal-target>` must be wrapped in `<MountingPortal>`.

This works:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <MountingPortal mountTo="#target-id">
      <portal-target name="destination" />
    </MountingPortal>

    <portal to="destination">
      <p>This should be rendered outside</p>
    </portal>
  </div>
</template>
```